# How to upload photos/file to server using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

Hi so I'm trying to allow users to upload a photo to a listing. I'm using dropzone.js and I have the form done, it works perfectly! except that photos don't actually upload to the folder "uploads/"

I have tried many many different ways spent days researching and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

Kindly note that it is a multipage form so I cannot post the whole form on here but ill try to share the important scripts!

Dropzone code:

```
  <head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

    <div class="container" >
        <div class='content'>
        <form action="create.php" method="post" type="file" name="file" class="dropzone" id="dropzonewidget" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       
    </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row form-block flex-column flex-sm-row">
      <div class="col text-center text-sm-start"><a class="btn btn-link text-muted" href="user-add-2.php"> <i class="fa-chevron-left fa me-2"></i>Back</a>
      </div>
        <div class="col text-center text-sm-end"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">save</button><i class="fa-chevron-right fa ms-2"></i></div>
      </form>
```

Now for the PHP script: I have 2 attempts that got close, the first actually makes its way into the database and the second just echo's all error scripts

Script 1: (kinda works)

```
 $uploadDir = 'var/www/uploads';
 $tmpFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

 // upload file to directory
 $fileName = $uploadDir.'/'.time().'-'. $_FILES['file'] 
 ['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($tmpFile,$fileName); {

 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO hosts(id, user_name, name, type, 
 country, city, state, zip, about, price, photo)
  VALUES('$id', '$user_name', '$name', 
 '$type', '$country', '$city', '$state', '$zip', 
 '$about', '$price', '$fileName')";
```

Script 2:

```
 $target_dir = "uploads/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"] 
 ["name"]);
 $uploadOk = 1;
 $imageFileType = 
 strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

 // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

 $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
 if($check !== false) {
  echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
  $uploadOk = 1;
 } else {
  echo "File is not an image.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
  }


  // Check if file already exists
  if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  // Check file size
   if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 1000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
   }

   // Allow certain file formats
   if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" 
   && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
   && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
   echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are 
   allowed.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
   }

   // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
   if ($uploadOk == 0) {
   echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
   // if everything is ok, try to upload file
   } else {

   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
   $target_file)) {
   echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( 
   $_FILES["file"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
   //$pictureName = "uploads". basename( 
   $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
   } else {
   echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your 
   file.";
   }
```

At the end of both of these attempts I have a simple insert query (p.s. I know about SQL injections, just trying to get it to work first.)

hope I didn't give you a headache

Just a heads up I am new to PHP and to SO so be kind and I hope a more experienced developer can help me out of these troubling times! Thanks in advance, and if you understand my issue please post some code not a vague response :) cheers

Comment: @KenLee the folder has full permission and I just changed it to './uploads';  no success  : (

Comment: @KenLee the first script that I wrote enters the photo path into the db table but when i go to the folder, its empty. I don't have access to the JS file but I assume its something I'm missing in my script?

Comment: Please see (and try) my suggested answer

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 0):

**For dropzone uploads** (multiple file uploads)

a. you do **NOT** need to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `method="post"` `type="file"` `name="file"`

b. No need to use submit button

c. As stated before, make sure there is a sub-folder known as `uploads` and it is write-permitted

d. To do further db maninpulation (e.g. insert), execute the insert query in the php , make sure using `$_FILES['file']['name']` when constructing the insert query

Hence, please amend your code to:

HTML

```
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

    <div class="container" >
        <div class='content'>
        <form action="create.php" class="dropzone" id="dropzonewidget">
       </form>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

create.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "./uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
   $status = 1;

// do further update in database
// please note that the file name is $_FILES['file']['name']
// make sure you use parametized prepared statement in your insert query
// to avoid SQL injection attacks
//
}
?>
```

Comment: Does not work, not it just stays on the page and doesn't submit anything to db, thank you tho! any other suggestions?

Comment: Please visit the following testing link and see what happens: http://www.owihk.com/upload/trigger1.php . Drop a few graphics files onto the dropzone box and see the effect . This is **exactly** the HTML above (you may view the source of the HTML)

Comment: okay I have the affect already... my question is that it needs to be uploaded to a folder in the server and the path to the user DB so other users can read the image